# URL rewriting : Apache configuration to prevent loading default folder index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With the exact same .htaccess file, my local LAMP server (via mamp pro) and the production server behave differently. I suppose there is a different configuration at stake, but which one?

On my local server, http://domain.com/section/item/ redirects correctly to http://domain.com/index.php?section=$1&item=$2

On my production server,  http://domain.com/section/item/ gives access to  http://domain.com/section/item/index.html

What can i do to make the production server behave like the development server?

Here is the htaccess file content in case it helps.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

#--------------------------------------------
# PRETTY URLS
#--------------------------------------------


# if the following conditions are met, SKIP the rewriteRules.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [L]

# Externally redirect to add missing trailing slash
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]

# SIX PARAMS
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&content=$4&id=$5&title=$6 [NC,L,QSA]

# FIVE  PARAMS
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&content=$4&id=$5 [NC,L,QSA]

# FOUR PARAMS
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3&content=$4 [QSA,L]

# THREE PARAMS : projects/touch/texts/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2&menu=$3 [QSA,L]

# TWO PARAMS: downloads
RewriteRule ^downloads/([^/]+)/$ index.php?section=downloads&item=$1 [QSA,L]

# TWO PARAMS:
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&item=$2 [QSA,L]

# TAG URL : index.php?tag=url+encoded+keyword
RewriteRule ^tag/([\w-]+)/$ index.php?tag=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# ONE PARAM
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ index.php?section=$1 [L,QSA]

#--------------------------------------------
# END PRETTY URLS
#--------------------------------------------

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does the `/section/item/index.html` exist on both the dev and production server?

Comment: yes, both file directory structures are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making 2 changes.

Add this line on top of your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Then change your 1st rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

**EDIT:** Also try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Comment: I get a 403 forbidden when accessing the folder http://domain.com/section/item/ (on both servers).

Comment: Which means you have `index.html` on both dev and production hosts?

Comment: Check my edit. Comment out suggested `DirectoryIndex index.php` line if you still get 403

Comment: i played around with your suggestions, and it seems setting
`DirectoryIndex index.php`+ 
`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`  does the trick, thank you!!!

Comment: I looked at the official documentation on MultiViews, but i cannot really make sense of it. Could I ask you to explain it in your own words?

Comment: `MultiViews` is Apache's own not-so-good way of making pretty URLs without explicitly using mod_rewrite rules. Anyone using `mod_rewrite` should turn off `MultiViews` to avoid these conflicts.

Comment: and adding ` -MultiViews`turns them off or on ?

Comment: Yes `-MultiViews` turns it off.

Answer (score 0):

> yes, both file directory structures are exactly the same

I don't know how exactly you've got everything setup, but it's *possible* that the order of modules being loaded is different between development and production (a long-shot), which could influence the order modules are being applied in the URL processing pipeline. It the order or something like mod_autoindex or mod_dir is different, thus causing a request for `/section/item/` to get resolved to `/section/item/index.html` **before** mod_rewrite gets a chance to do anything. That means this condition becomes true:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

And none of your other rules get applied, and thus `/section/item/index.html` gets served.

As to how to fix something like this, I suppose you can try turning off directory index in your server config (by commenting it out, everywhere), or set it to something non-existent in the directories that they are getting served:

```
DirectoryIndex _index.php
```